# Windows Server / Datacenter: set CPU affinity with > 64 cores

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, multiprocessing

SetThreadAffinityMask() allows one to set an affinity mask for 64 logical cores (processors). However, Windows Datacenter can have up to 64 CPUs, each with many cores (see [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/d7d27752-1dcd-4884-b002-3284db41ab2b/)).

How does one set threads for > 64 cores?

Ps. I am coding in C#, so a .Net answer is ideal, but an API one in C is fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following code to set the affinity for processor groups and CPUs:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
private struct _GROUP_AFFINITY
{
    public UIntPtr Mask;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort Group;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U2)]
    public ushort[] Reserved;
}

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern Boolean SetThreadGroupAffinity(
    IntPtr hThread,
    ref _GROUP_AFFINITY GroupAffinity,
    ref _GROUP_AFFINITY PreviousGroupAffinity);

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetCurrentThread();

/// <summary>
/// Sets the processor group and the processor cpu affinity of the current thread.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="group">A processor group number.</param>
/// <param name="cpus">A list of CPU numbers. The values should be
/// between 0 and <see cref="Environment.ProcessorCount"/>.</param>
public static void SetThreadProcessorAffinity(ushort groupId, params int[] cpus)
{
    if (cpus == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cpus));
    if (cpus.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("You must specify at least one CPU.", nameof(cpus));

    // Supports up to 64 processors
    long cpuMask = 0;
    foreach (var cpu in cpus)
    {
        if (cpu < 0 || cpu >= Environment.ProcessorCount)
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid CPU number.");

        cpuMask |= 1L << cpu;
    }

    var hThread = GetCurrentThread();
    var previousAffinity = new _GROUP_AFFINITY {Reserved = new ushort[3]};
    var newAffinity = new _GROUP_AFFINITY
    {
        Group = groupId,
        Mask = new UIntPtr((ulong) cpuMask),
        Reserved = new ushort[3]
    };

    SetThreadGroupAffinity(hThread, ref newAffinity, ref previousAffinity);
}
```

Comment: You invoke SetThreadProcessorAffinity several time for each group you want the process to run in?

Comment: @bananasplit Good question! A process can have a multigroup affinity. But a thread can never be assigned to more than one group at any time. The code above is thread based. AFAIK if you reassign a thread to a group other than initial, the process becomes multigroup one.

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN, SetThreadAffinityMask() sets the affinity for your current processor group, each of which can have 64 logical cores each. Change your group with SetThreadGroupAffinity(). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503(v=vs.85).aspx for more.

Comment: can i do it with WMIC?

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with more than 64 CPUs, you have to take processor groups into account.  Refer to MSDN for details:

[Processor Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405503.aspx)